# The Threejs BoxHelper size and position are incorrect

Tags: javascript

Here is the use of vue2, the model file format is gltf, this file is downloaded from the Internet, not only this model, other animated model surrounding box is also mostly incorrect.

Here is the code to use BoxHelper.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zFrA.jpg)

This is the actual effect
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wCNb.jpg)

I hope the box can accurately surround the model, hope to get your help, thanks!